# Unable to get selected value from list box in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Unable to get selected value from list box in IE 8

```
<select id="fileName" style="width: 100%;" size="3" name="uploadedfile">
<option id="my1Div">test1</option>
<option id="my3Div">test2</option>
<option id="my5Div">test3</option>
</select>
```

I am getting the value like the following

```
var myvalue= document.getElementById("fileName").value;
alert(myvalue);
```

Comment: Works properly on mozilla.........

Comment: define list box. Is it a ul/li, a select-element or what?

Comment: No simple Option box
<select id="fileName" style="width: 100%;" size="3" name="uploadedfile">
<option id="my1Div">test1</option>
<option id="my3Div">test2</option>
<option id="my5Div">test3</option>
</select>

Comment: A select-element that is. See Robert Grant´s answer.

Comment: and NickFitz´s if your sure it´s a single choice form control.

Comment: Yeah I thought I'd play safe and go with something that works with everything :)

Comment: i am using single choice control......

Answer (score 7):

```
var select = document.getElementById("fileName");
var myvalue= select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
alert(myvalue);
```

`select.value` appears in [the DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980), but has never been implemented by IE. The `selectedIndex` property works everywhere.

UPDATE: as anddoutoi points out in a comment to the original question, this assumes you are using a single-item `select`.

Answer (score 6):

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById("selectElementId");
var selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
```

This should be changed to:

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById("selectElementId");
var selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text;
```

Changing the `.value` to `.text` solves the problem and is compatible with all browsers.

Comment: a big thanks for that answer, have searched around for a good way to get selected element from listbox for more than an hour! =)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is with your HTML. Quoted from your comment:

```
No simple Option box <select id="fileName" style="width: 100%;" size="3" name="uploadedfile"> <option id="my1Div">test1</option> <option id="my3Div">test2</option> <option id="my5Div">test3</option> </select>
```

You have to actually specify a value for each `<option>`. Try this:

```
<select id="fileName">
    <option id="my1Div" value="test1">test1</option>
    ...
    <option id="my5Div" value="test3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hi thanks i was creating option in runtime now i have also add the value attribute it is working..........

Comment: Actually the `value` attribute is optional: it defaults to the content of the option. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-value-OPTION

Comment: **should** I just tested it, works in Firefox but IE8 doesn't default to the content.

Comment: I should add: When you're getting the value from `document.getElementById('fileName').value`. I didn't test for using `selectedIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var listbox = document.getElementById("list");
for(var i=0; i<listbox.options.length; i++)
    if(listbox.options[i].selected)
        alert(listbox.options[i].value);
```

Something like that?

**Edit:** typo!

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById("selectElementId");
var selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code to get a vaiable **columnName** from the SELECT box called **layerDetails.styleColumn** (SELECT tag has same name and Id), that works across ALL browsers  ...

```
var columnName = document.getElementsByName('layerDetails.styleColumn')[0].value;
if ( columnName == null || columnName == '' )
  {
  columnName = document.getElementById('layerDetails.styleColumn').value;
  }

if ( columnName == null || columnName == '' )
  {
  var select = document.getElementById('layerDetails.styleColumn');
  columnName= select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  if ( columnName == null || columnName == '' )
    {
    columnName= select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    }
  }
```